# how i can change Datetime format to (dd.mm.yyyy) in Netjs Prisma

Tags: postgresql, date, format, nestjs, prisma

i created db rows in schema.prisma file like below

```
model Home {
  id              Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  meal_date       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Date
  meal_day        String
  meal            Meal[]
}
```

but meal_date is looking very weird like below

[2022-08-08T00:00:00.000Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4a0e.png)

How i can change this format?

Answer (score 0):

The format of `DateTime` fields is not configurable. Prisma uses the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).